# how to get all combinations of str items of a list row-wise python

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I have a fasta file as below:

```
>seq1
AAAAAAAA
>seq2
TTTTTTTT
>seq3
CCCCCCCC
>seq4
GGGGGGGG
```

I want to get all combinations of the lines `(except the ones that start with > sign)`. The desired output should be:

```
AAAAAAAA
TTTTTTTT

AAAAAAAA
CCCCCCCC

AAAAAAAA
GGGGGGGG

TTTTTTTT
CCCCCCCC

TTTTTTTT
GGGGGGGG

CCCCCCCC
GGGGGGGG
```

My piece of code is here but the last step of making combinations is missing:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

list1=[]
with open('file1.fa', 'r') as file1:
    for record1 in SeqIO.parse(file1, 'fasta'):
        list1.append(record1.seq)


for i in list1:
    print(i)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
from itertools import combinations as com

lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
combi = list(com(lst, 2))

for entry in combi:
    print(entry[0])
    print(entry[1])
    print()
```

output

```
A
B

A
C

A
D

B
C

B
D

C
D
```

Comment: Thank you for your input - how can I print them column-wise as I mentioned in the desired output section?

Comment: loop over `combi` and print each entry

Comment: Unfortunately, It does not help - I need to print each item of each entry to be printed column-wise. I have been stuck with this for some hours - it would be appreciated if you could help.